# Unpack 12-bit data quickly (where the nibbles aren't contiguous; how to shuffle nibbles?)

Tags: c#, c++, avx, avx2, pixelformat

I need to unpack 12-bit data stored packed, 2 unsigned 12-bit fields stored in 24-bits. I'd like to store them in a byte[] in a little endian uint16 order.

The packed format is a bit odd; `byte[0]` is the upper 8 significant bits of the first 12-bit number and and `byte[2]` is the upper 8 significant bits of the second 12-bit number. The middle `byte[1]` has the lower 4 bits of both; the first value in the lower nibble and the second value in the upper.

Here's a visual: the full boxes are bytes, letters represent nibbles.  Lower addresses on the left, so SIMD bit-shift left will actually move data to the right across boxes but left within boxes.
[image]

I have written 2 working versions in C#.

```cs
        private byte[] Unpack12b2(byte[] input) //slower
        {
            int eod = input.Length / 3 * 3; //protect against file sizes that aren't a multiple of 3
            byte[] output = new byte[eod * 3 / 2];
            int j = 0;
            int loop = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < eod; i+=3)
            {
                j = i + loop++;
                output[j] = (byte)((input[i] << 4) | (input[i + 1] & 0xf));
                output[j + 1] = (byte)(input[i] >> 4);
                output[j + 2] = (byte)((input[i + 2] << 4) | (input[i + 1] >> 4));
                output[j + 3] = (byte)(input[i + 2] >> 4);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private ushort[] Unpack12b(byte[] input) //slightly faster
        {
            int outputIndex = 0;
            int byte1, byte2, byte3;

            int eod = input.Length / 3 * 3; //protect against file sizes that aren't a multiple of 3
            ushort[] output = new ushort[eod / 3 * 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < eod; i += 3)
            {
                byte1 = input[i];
                byte2 = input[i + 1];
                byte3 = input[i + 2];

                output[outputIndex++] = (ushort)((byte1 << 4) | (byte2 & 0xf));
                output[outputIndex++] = (ushort)((byte3 << 4) | (byte2 >> 4));
            }
            return output;
        }
```

This is the closest answer I've found, but the packed format in that question is much easier to deal with.
[SIMD unpack 12-bit fields to 16-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347928/simd-unpack-12-bit-fields-to-16-bit)

I'd really like to speed this up. The output is an array of 200+ million bytes so it's a lot of loops and this function is called repeatedly.

Any thoughts on how to speed this up would be appreciated. Ideally I'd like to implement something with AVX2 in C++, but I'm getting lost in how to shuffle in nibbles rather than bytes.

Comment: Since you tagged this AVX-512, hopefully its SIMD rotates can help deal with the weird nibble order... but no, unfortunately only 32 and 64-bit element size for rotates.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vprold:vprolvd:vprolq:vprolvq).  So maybe AVX-512VBMI SIMD bitfield-extract, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmultishiftqb if you don't mind targetting Ice Lake / Zen 4.  (Skylake-X is probably ok with an AVX2 256-bit vector version, unless you specifically care about SKX, then maybe there's something that could be done specifically for it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I'm not sure was happened with the tags, I meant to tag AVX2.

Comment: Oh, so you're not interested in an AVX-512 version at all :/  AVX-512 `vpternlogd` with a vector constant can bit-blend after 16-bit shifts.  Hard to visualize with the diagram having everything backwards (lowest-address byte first [so left shift actually goes right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351087/convention-for-displaying-vector-registers), and the contiguous bits across halves of 16-bit integer not actually contiguous).  Emulating that with AVX2, just AND / ANDN both sides if necessary before ORing.

Comment: You also untagged [c++], so this is now a C#-only question?  C# does have AVX2 intrinsics, but your question body still says C++.  (Of course, the real question of which sequence of machine operations would be efficient doesn't depend on the high-level language, as long as it has intrinsics for every SIMD instruction.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow, this problem is melting my brain. I can't even get the tags right. Everything looked right before it told me I couldn't post inline images. C# has intrinsics, but only for .NET Core.  Most of our other software is .NET framework and they're incompatible. My thought was a C++ dll that I can import the function into C# and that others could use in C++ as well.

Comment: I don't really know C#, but yeah if you can't use `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` intrinsics, then calling a foreign function on a big array is probably better than scalar.  Ideally you'd want to cache-block by only processing a chunk that will still be hot in L2 cache when you loop over it with your next step, or even process on the fly for whatever you're doing with it.  I seem to recall foreign function overhead being significant in C#, like "marshalling", but probably 64 KiB chunks are big enough to amortize function-call overhead (input 64K + output 85K = well under 256K L2 cache size.)

Comment: You can do soooo much better in pure C# than this.  Pick a nice block size that's a multiple of 3 bytes, say 3*128 = 384 bytes.  `Buffer.BlockCopy` from your `byte[]` to `uint[]` or `ulong[]`.  Every uint32 will contain 2 whole 12-bit segments, which can be pulled out at a cost of one bitshift (`>>`) and one bitmask (`&`) per segment.  Some segments will straddle uint boundaries, so repeat the BlockCopy with a different source offset and pick up the ones you missed.  Then move up to the next block of 384 bytes and repeat.  Nowhere near as good as SIMD but much faster than working with nibbles.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Note the weird bit-order: neither 12-bit field is contiguous within a 3-byte chunk.  Perhaps it would be on a big-endian machine, but even then I'm not sure.  (Maybe this was stored by packing code that made sense on a big-endian machine, but was run on little-endian?)  Also, some 12-bit fields will be split between 4-byte chunks if you just did a straight `memcpy` style of thing, since 3 byte chunks don't go evenly into 4-byte buckets.

Comment: @Peter: Ahh that does complicate things.  Note that my earlier comment did say " Some segments will straddle uint boundaries" and provide a suggestion for handling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use C# `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` to do this in C#, then yes calling out to a function created by a C++ compiler could be good.  To balance between marshalling overhead vs. cache misses, you might want to work in chunks of 64K input producing 85K output, which you read while it's still hot in L2 cache, before moving on to the next chunk.  But if you need random access to the unpacked output, you might be stuck with doing the whole thing at once and getting at best L3 cache hits, or even misses all the way to DRAM.

---

Most of the techniques from [SIMD unpack 12-bit fields to 16-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347928/simd-unpack-12-bit-fields-to-16-bit) are applicable, like doing a 32-byte load that splits down the middle of two 12-byte halves, setting up for a `vpshufb` which will get the 3 bytes we want into each 4-byte chunk.

**Moving nibbles around requires bit-shifts** (or AVX-512 instructions like [`vpmultishiftqb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmultishiftqb), a bitfield-extract).  x86 SIMD only has 16-bit and wider shifts, not 8-bit element size, unfortunately.  (Left-shift by 1 bit can be done by adding to itself, otherwise you can use a wider shift and AND with a mask to clear any bits that got shifted in across byte boundaries.)

Visualizing how a left or right shift will move bits between bytes is vastly easier with a [diagram where shift-left is left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351087/convention-for-displaying-vector-registers), which one might call "big endian", highest byte on the left like Intel uses in their manuals for SIMD shuffle instructions (e.g. [`punpcklbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/punpcklbw:punpcklwd:punpckldq:punpcklqdq)).  And like the comments in my answer on the linked 12-to-16 unpack question for a normal bit layout, where that layout makes it look like the two contiguous 12-bit fields it is (unlike here where it is indeed weird).  I'd normally use letters starting with A, but picked different ones to avoid confusion with your diagram.  (I used earlier letters for more-significant nibbles in this case; I sometimes go the other way around, to match up with the element numbering for shuffles, where `0` is the right-most element that gets loaded/stored from the lowest address, so D C B A in a diagram makes sense.)

```
high       low address
QR    ST    UV        # input format

QR ST  |  ST UV       # after a byte-shuffle replicates the middle byte while expanding

0Q RS  |  0U VT       # desired output.

 (QR<<4) | (ST>>4) in the high half.   Or QRSx>>4 in terms of 16-bit ops
 (UV<<4) | (ST&0x0F) in the low half.  Or xxUV<<4 merge with (STxx>>8)&0x0F
```

The initial byte-shuffle (`vpshufb`) that expanded 12 bytes to 16 (in each lane) could give us any arrangement we want within each 32-bit chunk, like `ST ST UV QR` or `UV ST QR UV` if either of those was a useful setup for 32-bit or 16-bit shifts (and AND/OR)

For example, if we had `ST QR` in the high u16, our desired (0QRS) could be obtained with a rotate-left by 4 bits of the 16-bit STQR to bring the T down to the bottom and left-shift the `UV` part.  Then mask to clear the garbage (T) in the high nibble.  But we don't have SIMD rotates until AVX-512, and even then [only in 32 and 64-bit element size](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vprold:vprolvd:vprolq:vprolvq).  And we'd need something different for the other 16-bit word.

A rotate can be done with `(x<<4) | (x>>12)`.  But if we're emulating it anyway, we could start with two different inputs, and/or shift by amounts that don't add to 16 or 32.

Starting with `UV ST | QR ST`, *32-bit* shifts (by 20 and 12) can create `00 00 | 0UV S` and `xQ RS | x0 00`.  We could OR those together without messing up the `UVS` or the `QRS` (slightly cheaper than a `vpblendw` on Intel), but that's not exactly what we want. Still, in general for problems like this it's worth considering 32-bit shifts.

A simple right shift by 4 bits (`_mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4)`) would turn `QR ST` into the `0Q RS` we want in the high u16 (word) of each u32 dword element.  So that's ready to `_mm256_blend_epi16` like in the older Q&A, if we can come up with something that generates `0UVT` at the bottom of a 32-bit element.

`0UVT` is trickier:  neither byte order (UV ST or ST UV) has the bits we want contiguous with each other.

But with `UV ST`, the right shift we want for the high half puts also the `U` and `V` nibbles in the right place, leaving just the problem of replacing the low 4 bits (`S`) with the `T` nibble.  In the original initial `v` (before the shift), we had a copy of `T` there, so 3 bitwise operations can "blend" it in.

**So it turns out `QR ST  | UV ST` is a good layout for the initial `vpshufb`, making the required data movement closer between the two u16 halves.**

### With just a shifts and 3 bitwise operations:

```
 QR ST | UV ST        # after vpshufb
 0Q RS | 0U VS        # after vpsrlw by 4
```

AND/OR between those two vectors can produce `0Q RS | 0U VT`, only needing to replace the low nibble in the low word.  (Otherwise keeping everything from the shift result).

```
 __m256i v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(in, c);        // QR ST | UV ST

 __m256i shifted = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4);     // 0Q RS | 0U VS
 __m256i t = _mm256_and_si256   (_mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000000F), v);  // 00 00 | 00 0T
 shifted   = _mm256_andnot_si256(_mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000000F), shifted); // 0Q RS | 0U V0
 __m256i output = _mm256_or_si256(shifted, t); // 0Q RS | 0U VT
```

Putting that into a function that loads 24 bytes and returns 32 (ready for the caller to store in a loop), borrowing the code from my answer on [SIMD unpack 12-bit fields to 16-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347928/simd-unpack-12-bit-fields-to-16-bit).  I adjusted the shuffle-control vector by swapping the low 2 bytes in each 4-byte chunk vs. that answer.
(`setr` takes args in little-endian order).  That gives us `UV ST` in the low word of each dword while still having `QR ST` in the high word.

```
// loads from before the first byte we actually want; beware of using at the start of a buffer
/* static */ inline
__m256i unpack12to16_weird_bitorder(const char *p)
{
    __m256i v = _mm256_loadu_si256( (const __m256i*)(p-4) );
   // v= [ x H G F E | D C B A x ]   where each letter is a 3-byte pair of two 12-bit fields, and x is 4 bytes of garbage we load but ignore

    const __m256i bytegrouping =
        _mm256_setr_epi8(5,4, 5,6,  8,7, 8,9,  11,10, 11,12,  14,13, 14,15, // low half uses last 12B
                         1,0, 1,2,  4,3, 4,5,   7, 6,  7, 8,  10,9, 10,11); // high half uses first 12B
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(v, bytegrouping);   // vpshufb
    // each 16-bit chunk has the bits it needs, but not in the right position
    // in each chunk of 8 nibbles (4 bytes): [ q r  s t | u v  s t ]

    __m256i shifted = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4);     // 0Q RS | 0U VS
    __m256i t = _mm256_and_si256   (_mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000000F), v);       // 00 00 | 00 0T
    shifted   = _mm256_andnot_si256(_mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000000F), shifted); // 0Q RS | 0U V0
    return _mm256_or_si256(shifted, t);            // 0Q RS | 0U VT
}
```

**This is only 4 instructions after `vpshufb`, and three of them are cheap bitwise booleans** that can run on any vector execution port on most recent Intel / AMD CPUs, even Haswell.  (https://uops.info/).  So one more uop than the simpler data arrangement in terms of front-end throughput.  Also, only one extra vector constant beyond the `vpshufb` control vector.

One AVX-512 `vpternlogd` could replace the three AND/ANDNOT/OR instructions, using the same constant to blend with bit granularity.  (Compilers will do this for you if you compile with `-march=skylake-avx512` or `znver4` or whatever; [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gDMpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHObxocjeWADUJvFueCwsoQTEoQB0CAfYJhoAgvcPAPovLGYArABseLteDCSTGQAGsuGYiFxvi8AO6YPDEdAvKKEEhYYgQNAMBQEXbIBANXYAKiSc2eJgA7FZHrtabs3h8fn8AG77eIAEXpJy%2B0NoqCY6C8LzSPIgu0xAhx9PePLwRLmECSAFpJHNdmT4tSHnSAPQ63bMg6ckyfCy7VS7AASuwA4rsAGK7bD7CluXact1m7UWk2c2kwhCxTC7TDAhC7egEAixXZ4BS7Ji7eJKqIAT2juyBCN2qCouwIMNQu3BKcIuxomFo6AUpATDHQ5tj8ckuzT0fjud2wAaUSYwGDcIj/IbUS8uLwwAYJEw5JpdKxUoZstb6cwwGISySoWAbPZzzpB65jOhSnOL0wW4AHBBPqRpLtb99a7tL6QKbXXwBOZ9cLikLgaLWv7/gEtJSP%2BiTFtIXC3rsepDjCuwErQeZeEo8YGFK4JaoeuF4Xhf6AcWpCgbs0iQdIsG0u%2BuxPtRH4/oB37FoBv4ama8EIBO4bIah6HlgiWGWPudKskaR48sKCBeFQVD0OeV4QMytZtmuG5eFuRjsSJtLwaG%2BLFt8pa4viAIgkhTDxgQgatoQ8ZlmEmDVipY67FO44MPmNkXMACC4ikaSOAIOlwfqoQhmGeLSQw5mdpebl4FEUT0PGEAtqpChzCA%2BymrsACOuzELSVkum6XgGsV%2BY5XujwhUuTK7AoXFUNGDbie8x7CsQtB4ApeBQkptaqgcZoHvBGgAIq7AASkIpW7Boci7AAakIdUyg1uLtdyPwvIYSIij8dIQB1kmnlwfXxGYEAaKoGj3Q9Gj2gsBrsXh40aAtn2Um690LQAKiFTV4C1Tl0ttnX7e5wp4KKp27edl3Xbdj0Pc9tbA6D6BveNU2zfNi0rRoIXEJgBDLJ58PQiQMOipjrW1gQb34bq%2BqTTNc0/QtS3LYDtUUjVTy1Y89W/P8gLAmCEKoFCsLwoiyKooisTvAK6AStiJkEkVJJkvzOF0qLLK7hJu18gKQqHd8Yoa4uG2/PKioqmq2lzqFBriSaZoWtadqOs6XMersXqNr6dIBkGEUGZG0ZFXGCZJimq6Zkw2adgWRYliiuIVlWNZ1g2Frx%2Blq4dnm3bEL2/a7IO5sjq5E5TqTs4PPB/0APLsu32X4tU5nWcGTUyXJM5u3ikq4kbK7Ruum7bruIUHlTwpk8QfXXre96Ps%2Br40V%2BP5/gBQGH6R4FcJBZ%2BwfBfKIbx/z8ZhuLYYvLOv8RRF/qR5FDaQVG7DRdF/4MTAkxICrEuA431FxXyFkUL30wPGGgxAhIG1pGJDkpsTzSVkvJC8eBrzKWnmpOeWkRohT0pFKExkopmQslZGy2d7K4kcs5Vsrl3Kxk8gPQq3F/L5CCgwFuY0wqeX0uGUyMUcx5nigwRKyUEHihLu2LKOUzQFSKo1KqXNyqsk0VtT4gsl72z%2BHyE2y8FDdV6nggahDhqajfg4hx8EvbmlUG4gm/wKrxl9OtY8fwuJmJ2tCfatMfiDUwSvAgF08FXRuqoWSGgqBgA4I9OYzNDzONyuo2kn0tqui%2Bn9HxY8An4QhpJFgasvBRAUH1AaXFazmLJtErcsTboAWSRoLgHSHppJGu7Fxn0CqFS0fkx61UhF0lJuTYglMgnInoPWWp1s%2BS1nqQtKIAFNmdI0K7bUGT9SyKSilThUdwxZiKp2ax3xsoDPysMvJv1PGsm8QY/Y/N2QcAWLQTgnxeB%2BBSbwVAnA3DWGsI1JYKxgwbB4KQAgmhPkLBBCAT4ZhLifE/BSSQGgvgYqxWYb4f5vkcEkLwFgEh7qkH%2BVoUgQKOC8AUCAQCcKAULDgLAGAiAUCoBYFuegZAKASh5XQAYwBz4BCwMyPAqxlp4EwDCduSRGCcBhTQWgscGUQCiPC0gKJmDEFTMq3guqGipnblEbQ1RmUwrQCcRgBB24MFoAagFpAsCjmAG4MQtAGXcF4FgCpRhxAuvwKTGozIEHaswKoaoY41gwrOJWbVPUojEBNR4LA2rzjHENQsOSfYFAyrlQqpVvqZCCBEGIdg4F%2BCCEUCodQLrdCEsMMYUFlh9CJQZZABYqAkgCJ9Uqdu8RdhKiVDidARpTDCUsGYRMSoKkrBuByBQIJUwGBBJgQF4biAXCwF2iACx2gCJcPWUYfg/zBCmCUMoegAoFEyJ4Fot7%2BEZF6NegYf4j21AmGevQX7OgTDff0OIn6f2PpyKB7oQGZggcPRC1YEgvk/L%2Bdq2l5pLxGW%2BC2YAyBkDFniJcMw4pcBK32BUCBvBmVaDSaQQMAoBgHv0JwElpAyWfEAlSwFnB6WMthfC1lHKIBIBtby2I5BKAieFXEUVV1XWYEldK2V8rFX/JVXQdVlAtUuuNfqw1OrQgmrNRahwembVsEEA6p12q3VeA9V6n1ML/UtqDdSkNlq8Dhp9dSqNMbox6YTUS6lybU36vTWsalWayW%2BtzQYYABalPFtU7wGtwhRDiGrbIOtahtW6ACAYIwKA202GTfuntfaMgDqHSOsdBAJ0cinVYGdc6F34iNCutdTAN1KiYMyVQnxwRbtiLuiN3bbCVnc84CArhf0XvrNBm9f470CJm3kQKr6r3Ab/eNjoDAugjHA%2Besb9gBF7cmMUTbkH9vZEOziKDG2YOIcWMsBDECmMcF%2BZS1DnB0OYew7h/DhHiP4CIEVaFcxKP8cRSASQFJLh4vRZi7FCPpBEpY2xjjX26W2F41RhFpAkUw7h0j3FxPMVvfiChl1tKIcsqQxwMwlPqXU747T0g260jOEkEAA%3D%3D%3D))

Blends with byte or wider granularity can use SSE4 / AVX2 `vpblendvb` with a control vector, which is 2 uops on Intel (1 on AMD) or only 1 for the SSE version.

---

#### Multiply-add instructions for moving+combining in a single-uop

One other possibility for moving nibbles around is to multiply by a power of 2, with [`pmaddubsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddubsw) (`_mm256_maddubs_epi16`, which treats one input as signed, the other as unsigned, and adds horizontal pairs of bytes into 16-bit results).  With the unsigned input as the data we want to combine (so it gets zero-extended to 16-bit), we can use `1<<4` = 16 as the signed multiplier.

After masking our inputs to clear the nibble we don't want from each 16-bit word, can we do everything with one `vpmaddubsw`?  No, because as a multiply it can only shift left. So we can't get the S from ST to the bottom of the 0QRS output we want.  (And we can't instead produce `QRSx` and right shift, because our 8-bit multiplier constants can't hold `256`.)

We could `vpblendw` between `QR ST | UV ST` and a `vpsrlw`-by-4 shift of that to generate `0Q RS | UV ST`...  But that doesn't quite work as an input for `vpmaddubsw` either.  The `Q` would need to get multiplied by `256`.  But `0QRS` is what we already want for that element, so we could just blend *after* `vpmaddwd`, between it and a shift, which is better instruction-level parallelism anyway since they can happen in parallel.

Details on getting `0UVT` from `UV ST`: AND to mask away the `S`, giving `UV 0T`.  Then treated as two u8 integers `UV` and `0T`, do `UV*16 + 0T*1` to get `UVT`.  So the other input for `pmaddubsw` for this element should be `10 01` (hex).

This would just cost one extra instruction (an 8-bit multiply-add) vs. the version for a simpler bit order.

```cpp
...
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(v, bytegrouping);

    // in each chunk of 8 nibbles (4 bytes): [ q r  s t | u v  s t ]
    __m256i lo = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4);                                   // [ 0 q  r s | xxxx ]
    __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000'ff0f));       // [  0000 | u v  0 t ]
    hi         = _mm256_maddubs_epi16(hi, _mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000'10'01)); // [  0000 | 0 u  v t ]

    return _mm256_blend_epi16(lo, hi, 0b10101010);
      // nibbles in each pair of epi16: [ 0 q r s | 0 u v t ]
```

`vpmaddubsw` is a multiply so it's not the most efficient instruction, but modern mainstream x86 cores have good throughput for it.  (2/clock since Skylake and Zen 3, 1/clock on Zen 2: https://uops.info/  On Intel at least, it competes for throughput with vector shifts, but Skylake and later can run those on port 0 or 1.  Its latency isn't a concern: out-of-order exec hides that and we're only doing a short chain of ops for each vector.)  Hopefully it doesn't waste too much power and reduce turbo frequency.

**This is strictly worse than the shift/and/andnot/or version,** which uses the same number of uops but more of them are cheaper, and it has fewer vector constants to load for setup.  I came up with this `pmaddubsw` version first; I'm leaving it in the answer as an example of a bit-movement technique that's sometimes useful in other problems.  If we didn't need the blend at the end to treat the two u16 halves differently, the `madd` version could be better.

Note that `madd` could work with a `QR ST  |  ST UV` byte order: you'd just line up the `0x10` multiplier with the other byte.  Unlike with 16 or 32-bit shifts where bits being contiguous across byte boundaries is important.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very detailed answer. I appreciate not just the code, but the thought process on how you got there. I've been struggling with this weird packed order all week. I honestly can't understand why it's done this way, it must have been faster somehow for them. I'll dig through this more in depth in the morning, but I wanted to thank you now.

Comment: This is so close, the last nibble of the each uint16 are swapped. C# function result: 75 03 22 01 AVX2 function result: 72 03 25 01.

Comment: Is that from the shift/and/andnot/or version, or the probably-slower shift/and/maddubs_epi16/blend version?  (They *should* both give the same result.)

Comment: @FadedSun: Oh, I see, le sigh, I got my initial diagram wrong. We actually want `0QRS` and `0UVT`.  (I probably got mixed up with left=high since I was still getting over trying to look at your left=low diagram and giving up on it).  I think that just means we want opposite things in the halves of the u32 element, so just changing the AND constant should work (and the multiplier for that version).  My code did "correctly" generate the values I intended it to; the mixup happened earlier!

Comment: Both versions were the same. I just got it working myself by changing 0x00'0F'0000 to 0x000000'0F on both the AND and ANDNOT. Yes I realized after looking back through that we were both thinking different byte orders. It's rough to think in reverse.

Comment: On my relatively old Kaby Lake CPU the AND/ANDNOT is 3x faster than my C# (this includes passing between C# and C++ dll.  The and/mad version took twice as long, but was still faster than the C# version. Thank you very much for finding not 1, but 2 solutions. I'll mark this as answered. Would you like to edit the AND and ANDNOT in the answer?

Comment: @FadedSun: Yeah, I'll edit, but a correct edit also needs to correct the diagram and swap every mention of `S` and `T`.  Thanks for confirming that the different constants worked, and the speeds on SKL/KBL (although I'm surprised the madd version was so much slower).  Re: thinking "in reverse": yeah, it's the context-switching that'll get you.  Once I got switched over to thinking based on my diagram, I had zero problems, it was just making the initial diagram that involved looking at things backwards.  Looking at the reference C# code, it's just which half gets the `byte2 >> 4` vs. `& 0x0f`.

Comment: @FadedSun: Ok, updated.  I'm surprised the `maddubs_epi16` version was that much slower on SKL.   https://uica.uops.info/ predicts both versions will run at one iteration per 2.5 cycles on Skylake (which is the same as Kaby Lake), just bottlenecked on front-end throughput if put in a loop with load/store, 2 pointer increments, and a loop branch.  https://godbolt.org/z/7rKEPdMeP with uiCA links in comments for asm loops that include them.

Comment: @FadedSun:   Your 2x slower result could perhaps have been [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646), or bad benchmark methodology like one run paying for page-faults and the other reusing the same buffers?  ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)).

Comment: @FadedSun: Also, this was only 3x faster than scalar C#?  I don't suppose the C# auto-vectorized at all (although you could try to check on https://sharplab.io/ or however you locally look at JIT asm), which would mean at *best* 1x 16-bit store per clock cycle (port 4 bottleneck on our Skylake / Kaby Lake CPUs), even if the byte loads + shifting can be done in 3 uops each.  So 2 output bytes per cycle.  vs. 32 bytes per 2.5 cycles = 12.8 B / c.  So you're probably bottlenecking on memory bandwidth; without that, the expected speedup is at least 6.4x. (Unaligned vector load/store should be ok)

Comment: The speed was not thoroughly tested and I have noticed some small run-to-run differences. Since both were originally swapping the lower nibble and the maddubs_epi16 noticeably slower, I focused more effort on the AND/ANDNOT. Both are still far faster then the original C#. You have far more in depth knowledge of the specific bottlenecks of different CPUs than I do. I'm happy with a fast solution that is not so processor specific that it performs poorly on other processors. I'm already brainstorming how to apply what I've learned to speed up other things. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @FadedSun: The thing I find interesting is that there was a difference when I expected none on Skylake / Kaby Lake.  Especially if they're bottlenecked on memory.  So if you have a test program, I might try it on my own Skylake system to see if there's an interesting effect, or if it was just benchmarking error.